# user friendly URL rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Could anyone advise on how to I can rewrite this url:

```
https://test.com/user/user.php?u=name
```

to

```
 https://test.com/user/user/name
```

Please?

Below is my rewrite rule but it's not doing exactly what I want.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/user/([^/]+) /user.php?u=$1 [L]
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/user/([^/]*)/?$ /user/user.php?u=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks thickguru, I tried it but it didn't work. Thanks for taking your time to help.